# Input HTML с автоподтягиванием результатов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Задача.
Клиент на фронте вводит адрес по русски.
Форма передает при каждом изменении значения информацию на мой контроллер.

На бэке у меня есть get метод в java контроллере который обрабатывает приходящую строку и возвращает ответ.

Это значение или несколько значений должно отобразиться под полем ввода.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста вариант поля со считыванием асинхронно данных с него и вывода ответа.

Comment: попробуй chosen https://habr.com/post/124899/

Answer (score 1):

Можно взять за основу [datalist](http://htmlbook.ru/html/datalist) и добавить ajax, пример реализации https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-autocomplete-dropdowns-datalist-element